# Where can I find the definition for ?android:attr/listItemFirstLineStyle

Tags: android

I tried digging around in https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res and google but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

In general `?android:attr/...` references the value of an attribute in the currently-applied theme ([Referencing style attributes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes)). Those attributes are defined in `res/values/attrs.xml` - however, there is no entry for `listItemFirstLineStyle` (neither in the current version nor in the first git contribution from 10/2008). The attribute seems to have appeared in [very early versions](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/ugWRmpSJxoY/ClLPCcNPN0IJ) of both`simple_list_item_X.xml` layouts though.

[Using listItemFirstLineStyle in my own layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085865/usng-listitemfirstlinestyle-in-my-own-layout-android) basically comes to the same result.